# Trying to get next line from file each time a variable is called

Tags: python

I am trying to make a flashcard program that when I press a button the next word in the file will show up, along with the definition

This is some code I found on here that was posted a while back but it doesn't do anything.

```
def nextWord():
with open('Words.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        nextLine = next(f)
        if 'A' == line.strip():
            print(nextLine)
```

I have looked for a while and haven't found a solution for it yet.

the text files are like this:

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
```

And the same with the definitions.

I have also tried this

```
def nextWord():
    with open('Words.txt') as f:
        count: int = 0
        for line in f:
            count = count + 1
            if count == 1:
                print(line)
```

but it can only do the first line, or whatever line I choose

It's sort of what I'm looking for, though I want it to go to the next line if the code was run again, I was thinking of possibly using a loop, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Where is there a button here?  Where and how are the words and definitions stored?  Your spec is far too vague.

Comment: @TimRoberts I edited the post to show how the text files are, and I don't need help with the buttons I already have that covered.

Comment: Code doesn't write itself, nor do SO denizens write it for you - please share what you tried and explain what problems you're having and people will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If ALL you want is a function that delivers a new word each time it is called, that's easy:

```
def nextWord():
    with open('Words.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip()
```